# Dynamic UI in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I would like to add a scrollable menu to a mobile app page.
Here Transfer, Accounts, Payment and Transaction are generated from an XML file.
The rest is static layout.
I am using Xamarin.Forms.
I would like to know how to generate UI components dynamically and attach them to a placeholder using Xamarin.Forms.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: there are numerous examples of building UI with XAML and programmatically on the Xamarin site.  What specifically don't you understand?

Comment: @Jason I want people to come up with their ideas of how to achieve the end. That way, if I see a solution that is better than I have come to have, I can adopt that solution. If my solution is better than all the solutions proposed or if no solution is proposed then I can post my solution. This is how I learn to code and people who have done that on Q&A sites like this have helped me save hours of work. I think I have a valid question.

Comment: @SandahAung It is a valid question. That said, I would recommend that you post your solution first, and ask for a critique if your solution is giving you issues.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic UI creation is simple like the people said and there are many examples. But i think the problem is creating your own control according to your needs. For example i ended up with writing my own button with image in it like this:

[image]

So you have to write a method that creates a vertical stack layout (lets say outer container),and add a horizontal container to that "outer container" (lets say inner container) than add an image and a label to this "inner container" and make "innerContainer.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center" etc. If you want border it goes complicated :)

[image]

```
Vertical Stack (whole container)
->Vertical Stack (height 2px) upper border
->Horizontal Stack (to hold middle controls,left border,inner image and text holder, right border etc.)
    ->Horizontal Stack (width 2 px) left border
    ->Vertical Stack (layoutOptions=Fillandexpand)
        ->Image (layoutOptions=Center)
        ->Label (layoutOptions=Center)
    ->Horizontal Stack (width 2 px) right border
->Vertical Stack (height 2px) lower border
```

So you have to join the controls like this hierarcy. First think how can you draw your control with existing controls than code it :) Hope i made my self clear.

Comment: Be careful using this strategy within Table Cells. Nesting StackLayouts like this can have dramatic performance penalties.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use "Collection View" which is new feature of xamarin.forms or "bindable layout" to make it dynamic.

Comment: Please elaborate