# Xamarin Forms Button set Content

Tags: button, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have a very common problem, but I couldn't find any valid solution.
I want to create a `Button` able to contain more than a simple `Label` or `Image`. In fact, Xamarin `Button` exposes only `Text` and `Image` properties, but in my case I want to construct a more flexible set of controls (e.g. a StackPanel with a list of controls).

I implemented a `ContentView` acting as a `Button` after having added `TapGestureRecognizer` and it works from the pure functional point of view. What I don't like is the missing of all Visual States of a `Button`.
Therefore, I was thinking how to implement a Custom Renderer of a `Button`. I would like to expose a `ContentPresenter` BindableProperty and then set that property to the `Button.Content` (speaking in UWP terms) in the Renderer class. I think this could be a solution, the problem is that I don't know how to "cast" a `Xamarin.ContentPresenter` to a `UWP.ContentPresenter`. Do you have any idea about how to implement a `Button` able to contain any generic Content?

Comment: When we face this scenario, we also create our own contentview, but overlay it with a transparant button ( so no tapgestures needed ) and at ButtonClicked we trigger a small animation on the contentview to simulate keypress.

Comment: Please see my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824184/dynamic-ui-in-xamarin-forms/41345666#41345666 it may show you a way